# Paste into an existing frame

Tags: adobe-illustrator, copy-and-paste

Using Illustrator. I have an image which I have pasted in and resized as I wish. I now want to replace that image with another from the clipboard. The image is effectively embedded. Is it possible to paste in whilst automatically constraining the pasted in image to the same size as the one already there. Effectively replacing the existing image with a resized other image. I can't use place because I'm taking part of another image and not the whole thing. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Is your image embeded or linked? If you turn it into a linked imaged you can go to the Links window and update link to a new image.

Comment: I know that but as I said I'm only taking a portion of an image, not the whole thing. Thanks for trying!!